# I'm not able to write any thing in my MS WORD 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

I installed ms word 2007 in windows xp.
I have some existing word files but I am unable to edit them.

Toolbars are disabled as you can see the pic.

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 2):

Possibly your document is opened in [protected view](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx):

> Files from the Internet and from other potentially unsafe locations
>   can contain viruses, worms, or other kinds of malware that can harm
>   your computer. To help protect your computer, files from these
>   potentially unsafe locations are opened in Protected View. By using
>   Protected View, you can read a file and see its contents while
>   reducing the risks.
>
> Protected View is a read-only mode where most editing functions are disabled. There are 
>   several reasons why a file opens in Protected View: .........
>
> If you must read the file, and don't have to edit it, you can remain
>   in Protected View. If you know the file is from a trustworthy source,
>   and you want to edit, save, or print the file, you can exit Protected
>   View. After you leave Protected View, it becomes a trusted document.

Answer (score 2):

Note the top part of your screenshot:

[image]

Your document was opened in Microsoft Word in compatibility mode. A short summary as per this [article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/word-help/use-word-2007-to-open-documents-created-in-previous-versions-of-word-HA010044475.aspx):

`*Compatibility Mode ensures that no new or enhanced features in Office Word 2007 are available while you are working with a document, so that people who are using previous versions of Word will have full editing capabilities.*

The workaround is to [convert](http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/convert-older-office-documents-to-office-2007-or-2010-format/) this document. Converting the document will allow you to use all the latest features of MS Word. You can convert the document by going to the Info (or File) button and selecting the 'Convert Option'.

[image]

Please make a backup of the document before converting. You will note after conversion your document will have a .docx extention.

Comment: This is a just file name

Comment: What is at top part of the screenshot ?

Comment: Copy of Copy of BSF [Compatibility Mode]

Comment: what is compatibilty mode ? I check another file which is also open in this mode but it work well.